# Create Event C# SDK Failes - Getting (OAuthException) (#324) Missing or invalid image file

Tags: image, events, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to create an event using the C# SDK. I am using the code from the following blog:

http://facebooksdk.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/facebook-create-event.html

And I am using an image that I copied from an existing event on Facebook.

I am getting however the following error:

(OAuthException) (#324) Missing or invalid image file

Does anyone have an idea how to make it work?

Many thanks!

The code is as follows:

```
 public string CreateEvent()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
        Dictionary<string, object> createEventParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        createEventParameters.Add("name", "My birthday party )");
        createEventParameters.Add("start_time", DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToUniversalTime().ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")));
        createEventParameters.Add("end_time", DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).AddHours(4).ToUniversalTime().ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")));
        createEventParameters.Add("owner", "Balaji Birajdar");
        createEventParameters.Add("description", " ( a long description can be used here..)");

        //Add the "venue" details for the event
        JsonObject venueParameters = new JsonObject();
        venueParameters.Add("street", "dggdfgg");
        venueParameters.Add("city", "gdfgf");
        venueParameters.Add("state", "gfgdfgfg");
        venueParameters.Add("zip", "gfdgdfg");
        venueParameters.Add("country", "gfdgfg");
        venueParameters.Add("latitude", "100.0");
        venueParameters.Add("longitude", "100.0");
        createEventParameters.Add("venue", venueParameters);

        createEventParameters.Add("privacy", "OPEN");
        createEventParameters.Add("location", "fhdhdfghgh");

        //Add the event logo image

        //You can add the event logo too
        FacebookMediaObject logo = new FacebookMediaObject()
        {
            ContentType = "image/jpeg",
            FileName = @"C:\DevProjects\O2\o2PriorityFB\o2PriorityFB.Web\Images\logo.jpg"
        };

        logo.SetValue(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(logo.FileName));
        createEventParameters["@file.jpg"] = logo;

        JsonObject resul = fb.Post("/me/events", createEventParameters) as JsonObject;
        return resul["id"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Good luck using old C# SDK code.  You really should be using 6.0 of the SDK that came out this year.  Otherwise, maybe you should contact the blog author for assistance to see if they have any ideas.

Answer (score -1):

You need to include a valid access token in the request. Also, I would recommend upgrading to V6 of the Facebook C# SDK. For the version you are using though you need to pass the access token into the constructor of FacebookWebClient as follows:

```
var fb = new FacebookWebClient("valid_facebook_access_token");
```

Comment: Hi, I do have the access token, it is already being populated, and everything works when I remove the image, it is just when adding the image that I get the error.

Comment: It gives an invalidToken-exception-like error, when your accesstoken is invalid